# Is it possible open excel csv file directly into microsoft excel or other excel supported application via PHP code

Tags: php, csv

I need help in how I can open excel csv file directly into microsoft excel or other excel supported application via PHP code.

Currently I am able to only download that CSV file but I need to directly open it in supported application.

So is it possible?
Thank you in advance for any help.

For download csv file I use following php script

```
<?php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=uploads/shipping.csv");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
readfile("uploads/shipping.csv");
?>
```

Comment: It is possible on FIrefox browser. But you cannot call the default program for csv using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible using PHP. Either you set it on the Firefox Browser or Google Chrome download action. [Here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_download-actions) is the intruction on how you can do it on the Firefox browser and [here](http://www.presentermedia.com/blog/2013/10/my-file-automatically-opens-instead-of-saving-with-chrome/) is the one for chrome.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Lee Balino .

Comment: @AshishPatil NP lad. Just accept the answer and carry on. :D

Comment: Yes sure @Lee Balino I accept It and thank you again for help me through such great information :)